# How write parseJSON universal function? Swift

Tags: json, swift, generics, jsondecoder

I have different structs as my dataModels.
when i want to parse data with JsonDecoder().decode i need set a **.Type.self** in .decoder(**SomeType.self** , from: data)

I want write a support function which can return right Type respectively.
something like this
But I don't know how...

```
func check<T>(string: String) -> T
if string == "something" {
return Something.type
}

func parseJSON(from data: Data , with address: String)-> Codable? {
let type = check(string: address) 
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
let decodedData = try decoder.decode(type.self, from: data)
return decodedData
} catch let error {
print(error)
return nil
}
}
```

WHEN I WRITE THE code below, Everything works fine. But I always have to write parseJSON func with little difference over and over again

```
  func fetch(from adress: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: adress) else {print("can't get URL from current urlAdress"); return}
        let json = makeHttpBody(from: adress)
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url , cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy)
        request.httpMethod = K.post
        request.setValue(K.contentType, forHTTPHeaderField:K.applicationJson)
        request.timeoutInterval = Double.infinity
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, responce, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
            if let safeData = data {
            
                if adress == K.balanceUrl {
                if let parsedData = self.parseJsonBalance(from: safeData) {
                    self.delegate?.didUpdateData(with: self, with: parsedData)
                }
                } else if adress == K.projectsUrl {
                    if let parsedData = self.parseJsonProject(from: safeData) {
                        self.delegate?.didUpdateData(with: self, with: parsedData)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

  func makeHttpBody(from StringData: String) -> [String: Any] {
        switch StringData {
        case K.balanceUrl:
            return K.authorization
        case K.projectsUrl:
            return K.projects
        default:
            return ["none" : "none"]
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have a _string_ telling you what type to decode? Suppose you were able to do this, how do you intend on using the decoded thing returned by `parseJSON`? All you know about it is that it is `Codable`. You won't be able to do much with it, will you?

Answer (score 3):

Your approach cannot work, you have to use a generic type constrained to `Decodable`. Checking for strings at runtime is not a good practice.

This is a reduced version of your code, the error is handed over to the caller

```
func parseJSON<T : Decodable>(from data: Data) throws -> T {
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
}
```

Then you can write (the return type must be annotated)

```
let result : [Foo] = try parseJSON(from: data)
```

---

Or if you want to specify the type in the function

```
func parseJSON<T : Decodable>(from data: Data, type : T.Type) throws -> T {
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
}

let result = try parseJSON(from: data, type: [Foo].self)
```

Comment: sorry, I could not understand your answer, but I supplemented my question with a code with which everything works the way I want, but this causes code duplication